# Angular 7 Router: use default title if one not provided in route data

Tags: angular, angular-router, rxjs6

Following several articles and SO posts, I have configured my app to display the page title to be a router data parameter of "title":

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BadgesComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Design System - Badges'
    }
  }
];
```

However, some of my routes may not have this parameter added; in that case I want to display a catchall title, like just "Design System".  The code I pieced together (below) looks for the data element, but I don't know how to add a fallback to a simple string if the data element is missing.

It's worth noting that the `index.html` has a `title` of the default I want, which displayed before I added this code.  After I added the code, it gets overwritten — and `http://localhost:8082/#/badges` displays as the page title (for example)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { map, filter, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map(route => {
          while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
          return route;
        }),
        filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
        mergeMap(route => route.data)
      )
      .subscribe(event => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set the default title in the head of html and let router change it ?

Comment: There is a title in `index.html`, but after I added the above code it displays the URL instead, such as `http://localhost:8082/#/badges`.  I find this confusing, so that's why I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this inside subscribe code that you already have?

```
.subscribe(event => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title'] || 'Design System'));
```